# Tracking email with MVC and image (pixel)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, http

I was trying to achieve email tracking to my MVC application, i have googled for some help i am able to find something which describes that we need to add image along with the mail body

```
`<img src="..." style="height:1px !important; width:1px !important; border: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important" width="1" height="1" border="0">`
```

which will increase HTML Count when the mail being opened.
since i am new to this technology i am unable to figure the events when to capture the response (while opening the image)?

i am not seeing complete reference, can anyone please suggest how to achieve this  in MVC?

thanks in advance..,

Answer (score 1):

It's just basic HTTP methods.. you create a controller which returns the pixel and accepts parameters and do some serverside code when the image is requested using the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I've done (and checked) via redirect to static resources. Java/Spring looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/p")
public String pixel(int id, String mail) {
    .....
    return "redirect:/static/images/px.png";
}
```